# How to store returning values of a stored procedure select query in MySql and c#

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, return-value

Though there are many questions in Stack Overflow regarding this problem I didn't able to figure it out properly.

Could anyone can help me to figure this out.

This is the stored procedure as,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `procName`(IN RequestName CHAR(100))

BEGIN

DECLARE RequestName char(100);
SET 2RequestName = RequestName;

set @x = CONCAT('SELECT tcity FROM `t_table` WHERE tname = \'', 2RequestName ,'\';');

PREPARE stmt FROM @x;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SELECT @x;

END
```

I need return the value of `tcity` field selected with

```
set @x = CONCAT('SELECT tcity FROM `t_table` WHERE tname = \'', 2RequestName ,'\';');
```

on a web page C# ASP NET

But the value of `@x` variable, tested on SP in MySql, it's

```
SELECT tcity FROM `t_table` WHERE tname = 'MSD Health';
```

I need get on a web page C# ASP NET the value

```
Boston
```

I have been having difficulty returning a value to a C# application from a Stored Procedure.

**Editing question**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `procName`(IN RequestName CHAR(100))

BEGIN

DECLARE RequestName char(100);
SET 2RequestName = RequestName;

set @x = CONCAT('SELECT tcity FROM `t_table` WHERE tname = \'', 2RequestName ,'\';');

PREPARE stmt FROM @x;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

the output of SP is `Boston`

Comment: Executing the procedure you receive TWO rowsets. First contains the data which you need (produced by `EXECUTE`), the second - variable text (produced by `SELECT @x`). Remove SELECT statement simply - you don't need in it.

Comment: @Akina thank you for reply. I have editing my question with new version. I have error. But i'm sure i didn't understand your suggestion, sorry

Comment: I have NOT said to add `SELECT stmt;` !!! Remove it. And add NOTHING.

Comment: @Akina Okay, now the output of SP is `Boston`. But how to do returning the value `Boston` to a C# application from a `Stored Procedure` ?

Comment: C# executes a query and receives output rowset. No difference does the query is `SELECT` or `CALL` - so simply execute `CALL proc_name({parameters});` and process the output like you execute simple `SELECT {columns} FROM ...`.